# git update branch after commit on master

Tags: git, version-control

I have the following repo structure:

```
MA ---o---o---o---T1-
        |
B1      \---o--
              |
B2            \---o---o
```

where `MA` is `master`, `B1` and `B2` are branches, `o` is commit, `-` is development and `T1` is some time point

Now you see that after I did the first commit on `MA`, I created a new branch `B1`. Then worked on `B1`, then created `B2` and worked on it as well.

My problem is now that I did two more commits on `MA` **after** I have created the branches. But I want that the whole branching happens at time `T1` - so that my `B1` have all 3 master commits as basis.

So couple of questions here:

1. Is there some (easy) way to *repoint* `B1`?
2. What is going to happen to `B2` if I manage to *repoint* `B1`? I want to preserve the fact that `B2` has the commit on `B1` as basis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure: rebase `B1`, then `B2`.
You only needs to mark the old B1 state before doing it:

```
git checkout B1
git branch oldB1
git rebase MA
```

At this staged, `B2` is unchanged:

```
MA ---o---o---o---T1---o B1
        |
oldB1   \---o
             |
B2           \---o---o
```

Now a `rebase --onto` will move `B2` commits (the one between the `oldB1` HEAD -- excluded -- up to `B2` HEAD -- included --).

```
git checkout B2
git rebase --onto B1 oldB1 B2
git branch -d oldB1
```

That will give:

```
MA ---o---o---o---T1---o B1
                       |
B2                     \---o---o
```

Comment: Thank you. Couple of questions here: why do I need to mark the old B1 state? Why do I have to use `rebase --onto` for B2? Why not the same procedure as for B1?

Comment: @Anton Because `B1` commits are already applied to `master`. In theory, a rebase of `B2` (which would include the old `B1` commits) should ignore those already applied `B1` commits, but I bypass that entirely, by doing a `rebase --onto` which focuses only on `B2` commits. Hence the need to mark the old `B1` since, after the first rebase, `B1` has changed location.