# git rebase onto in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: git, intellij-idea, git-rebase

I want to move a range of commits to another branch with rebase in IntelliJ IDEA. The process works flawlessly on the command line, but I can't get it to work in IntelliJ IDEA (version 15.0.1).

The following is what I do on the command line:

`<feature-branch>`: branch with the changes
`<integrate-branch>`: branch to which I want to move the changes
`<commitId-rangestart>`: commit id of the parent of the range start
`<commitId-rangeend>`: commit id of the range end

```
git checkout develop
git checkout -b <integrate-branch> develop
git rebase --onto <integrate-branch> <commitId-rangestart> <commitId-rangeend>
git rebase HEAD <integrate-branch>
git push -u origin <integrate-branch>
```

I configure the IntelliJ IDEA rebase dialog as follows:

```
Branch: <feature-branch>
Onto: <integrate-branch>
From: <commitId-rangestart>
```

This results in the following git command line:

```
git checkout <feature-branch>
git -c core.quotepath=false rebase -i -v -m --onto <integrate-branch> <commitId-rangestart> <feature-branch>
```

This does not lead to the desired result. I tried any combination in the rebase configuration, but no success.

Is there a way to use IntelliJ IDEA to achieve the same result as on command line?

**Edit:**
The result should be, that the commit range from `<feature-branch>` are copied to `<integrate-branch>`. This is what happens when I do the described steps on the command line. [This post](http://weblog.avp-ptr.de/20120928/git-how-to-copy-a-range-of-commits-from-one-branch-to-another/) has a good description, including graphics, which describes what happens and what the result should be.
Depending on how I configure the IntelliJ IDEA rebase dialog, there are slightly different results from the process with IntelliJ IDEA. In the configuration described above, the `<feature-branch>` is rebased onto the HEAD of `<integrate-branch>`, no changes in `<integrate-branch>`.

Comment: `<commitId-rangestart>`: commit id of the **parent** of the range start: make sure to use the right rangestart.

Comment: Yes, I use the right rangestart, I'm pretty sure, since it works on the command line.

Comment: "This does not lead to the desired result.": could you describe what you see vs. what you expect?

Comment: Edited the question, added a description of the desired result.

Comment: That is a good description of what you expect, but what do you see? How IntelliJ fails in that rebase?

Comment: Edited the question again, added a description of the actual result.

Comment: The `<feature-branch>` is rebased onto the `HEAD` of `<integrate-branch>`: that s good no? A branch should be rebased on top of the `--onto` one.

Comment: No, I need the commit range from `<feature-branch>` copied onto the HEAD of `<integrate-branch>`. I want no changes in `<feature-branch>`, only new commits in `<integrate-branch>`. IntelliJ rebases the `<feature-branch>` and there are no changes in `<integrate-branch>`. This is not the desired result.

Comment: Mmm... that is the part where a schema similar to the ones I did in http://stackoverflow.com/a/33449886/6309 could help us understood what is wrong here.