# Is there any easy solution or automated one to update git branches after main/master changes?

Tags: git, automation, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have a repo that contains some shell script and a sample `env`. When I create a branch, I will change the sample `env` and make it customized. After push changed `env`, GitLab CI/CD triggers and all files will copy somewhere and deploy them.

In other words, assume I have a main repo that has these files:

```
run.sh
destroy.sh
.gitlab-ci.yml
env
```

And I want custom `env`, so create branch X that has these files:

```
run.sh
destroy.sh
.gitlab-ci.yml
env*
```

Name of `env` file not change, just its content will differ.

My issue starts when I want to develop files in main! I mean, if I want change `run.sh` then this should be changed in all other branches and then CI/CD pipeline of all branches will trigger.

The schema is something like this (adopted from [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33449749/git-update-branch-after-commit-on-master)):

```
MA ---o--------------o---->
        |   |         |
Y       |   \o--------+--->
        |             |
X       \o------------+--->
```

Where MA is master, X and Y are branches, o is commit, - is development and + is updating branches.

I know by recreating branch or merging them, this issue can be resolved, but this is a hard thing when we have lots of branches. I search for an automated solution to update all branches based on main/master.

P.S. `env` file shouldn't update in branches, but other files should. Also, `env` file is the only thing changes in branches.

Comment: There is no easy solution to using Git for configuration management (specialize some file per-branch). The easy solution is to keep all configurations in one single branch, over multiple files or whatever.

Comment: I suppose you could automate the process, but you'd have to decide what you want to do when conflicts arise. You might also consider just putting these files in another place altogether, like a separate repository, where you can just pull the contents in from the remote source as-needed, removing the need to keep anything in sync at all.

Comment: @sytech I think in my case, there is not any conflict because sample `env` never change.

Comment: @Guildenstern thanks, but I think it makes more complexity in the future.